# How to remove or resize javafx linechart series stroke dots

Tags: java, javafx, charts, linechart, stroke

i want to remove the dots of my javafx linechart series stroke.
Actually it looks like this:
[image: my-chart]

how can i remove or resize the red marked dots?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hide that dots using CSS:

```
.default-color0.chart-line-symbol { 
    -fx-background-radius: 0.0px;
    -fx-padding: 0.0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this in the Java code:

```
chart.setCreateSymbols(false);
```